# Is it alright to say something is super great

Tags: meaning, phrases

I would like to know if it's alright to say something is **super great**.

Example:
  Let's build this house super great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "alright" is a bit ambiguous and subjective here. If you are asking if it is grammatically correct to use the phrase "super great" then no it is not. If you asking if would be socially accepted, that would depend entirely on who you were presenting the phrase to and their flexibility when it comes to proper grammar. It would not be "alright" to say this to a teacher/professor, but likely would be to say it to any peers who have a lower regard for grammar than an educator would.